# How to resolve INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE?

Tags: java, android, memory, runtime-error

I just filled my internal memory(16GB) with big stuff of movies. Before that application was running in my device perfectly. After that it is showing error during installation of application as:-

```
Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE
```

I deleted enough data after that and there is 163 MB is available. See [image: Screenshot]

But still it's not running my application and printing the same error in Console. If anybody have experience of tackling such error please share with me. I am stuck here from last 2-4  hours. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line.

Comment: Maybe 163M isn't enough.

Comment: Whats that on the bottom of your screenshot there in the SD Card section? "Not enough storage space"? Either, 163MB is not enough for your app, or the app you're trying to install wants to install itself to /sdcard perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Add **android:installLocation="preferExternal"** for `<manifest>` tag of manifest file.

Or if you are using emulator

Check this [article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDevelopmentProblems/article.html#androidproblemresolution_insufficientmemory).

An Android virtual device provides by default only 64M for the storaging Android applications. You can clean your installed application by **restarting the emulator and selecting the `Wipe user data`** flag.

Alternatively you can set the data partition size. If you press edit on the AVD, you can **set the Ideal size of data partition property** via the New button.